# “Suspicious sign-in prevented”. Suspicious or not?

Tags: gmail, hacked

Yesterday I got an email from Google saying that my Hotmail address had been compromised. Snip below.

> Someone recently tried to use an application to sign in to your Google Account, x--------x@hotmail.co.uk. We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt:
>
> Tuesday, July 10, 2012 8:24:23 PM GMT
> IP Address: 77.116.246.31 (drei.com)
> Location: Vienna, Austria

The thing is, I recently moved to Austria. I took out a SIM from 3 (aptly named Drei in Austria) — it is a superSIM. The attempted hack was from `drei.com`.

So, was it me using the SIM network which is linked with that IP address and Google thought it was a "fritzle" or someone trying to hack me?

Although I can't remember logging into my Hotmail address, I do have it linked with my iPhone on emails. To be honest, I thought Hotmail was a Microsoft product anyway so I was shocked that Google even contacted me.

Or, was it a 3 employee that had intercepted my details somehow?

Bear in mind the fact that I gave no information out when purchasing the SIM.

It’s a mystery, but maybe someone can provide an answer about SIM networks etc.

P.S.: I doubt it was a phishing email.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here:

1. It is a fake e-mail from someone trying to look like Google. We would be able to confirm whether it's genuine or fake if you give us the whole header of the e-mail.
2. It is a genuine e-mail from Google, Someone tried to connect their Hotmail account to your Gmail account using some application (may be a WebApp or a Smartphone App) but failed to do so as he did not have your password. Even here, you have nothing to worry about. Anyhow, to be in the safe side, you can consider that someone whats to gain asses over your account(s) and change your password(s), Security Question and other Security settings.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable reason (if it wasn't a phishing email) that it was sent from Google if it was a Microsoft email would be if you have a Google account that uses your Hotmail address (like, if it's a Youtube/Google+/Etc. account that doesn't have a seperate GMail account linked to it).

Unless you have reason to think otherwise, it was probably just your iPhone connecting to your Google account. If someone at 3 intercepted your login details (which would be next to impossible, considering that the connection to Google Account servers is secured), they would probably be smart enough log in from a non-3 IP address :P